# Jquery .next() not working as expected

Tags: jquery

So I've got this html

```
                <div id="content_div">
                    <div>
                        <img src=""/>
                        <img src="" />
                        <img src="" />
                        <div class="test">

                        </div>
                        <img src="" />
                        <img src="" />
                        <img src="" />
                        <div class="test">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this Jquery

```
            $("#content_div > div > img").click(function()
            {
                $(this).next("div").slideDown();
            });
```

When I click on image ( Which I have in my code, not here though) I am expecting next div(after clicked image) to slidedown but nothing happens. I'm almost sure that I'm selecting it wrong because if I change $(this).next("div").slideDown(); to $(".test").slideDown(); it works, though both divs opens and I just want to open one, what's the problem? (I have a proper css, so that's not the case)

Comment: What you want to do won't work, as far as I know.  `.next` looks to the **very next** element, and in your markup in many cases the next element is an image, not a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case this should work:

```
$(this).nextAll('div:first').slideDown();
```

Comment: I don't think so - look at the markup.  There's multiple divs that will open given your code, and it sounds like the OP only wants the "next" div to open.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out, I thought that .next works on all next siblings, my bad. I'll accept your post in 5mins.

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like you are not using the correct function.

From http://api.jquery.com/next/

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves
>   the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

So if you click the first image, it's going to give you empty set because the next sibling is not a div.

Try with nextAll
http://api.jquery.com/nextall/

```
$(this).nextAll("div").first().slideDown();
```

Comment: No, that will open all the divs after the img, the OP just wants one opened.

Comment: That'll do it (the `.first` is the key...)